# Why do I get this exception when .NET try to execute a controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am pretty new to C# / ASP.NET MVC framework and I have the following problem.

I have this view named `DeleteExecutableType.cshtml`:

```
@model DataModel.MaliciousCode.Malicious

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DeleteExecutableType";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MasterPageMobile.cshtml";
}

<h2>DeleteExecutableType</h2>

<h2>Malicious: @Model.Id</h2>
<h2>Fix: @Model.MaliciousCodeExecutableType[0].Title (id: @Model.MaliciousCodeExecutableType[0].Id)</h2>

<p>
    Confermare la cancellazione dell'Executable Type "@Model.MaliciousCodeExecutableType[0].Title" ?
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteExecutableType", "EditingMalicious", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="hidden" name="executableTypeId" value ="@Model.MaliciousCodeExecutableType[0].Id" />
    <input type="hidden" name="maliciousId" value ="@Model.Id" />


    <div data-role="controlgrup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Malicious", new { id = Model.Id })#tab-3" data-mini="true"  data-inline="true" data-role="button"  >Annulla</a>

        <input type="submit" value="Delete" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" />
    </div>
}
```

When the user clicks on the `Delete` button submit the form, the method `DeleteExecutableTypePost()` defined on the `EditingMaliciousController` class is invoked.

Here it is:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteExecutableType")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteExecutableTypePost(long maliciousId, long currentExecutableTypeId)
{
            if (maliciousId == null | currentExecutableTypeId == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            manager.openConnection();
            try
            {
                manager.deleteSingleExecutableType(maliciousId, currentExecutableTypeId);
            }
            finally
            {
                manager.closeConnection();
            }

            return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Edit", "Malicious", new { id = maliciousId }) + "#tab-2");
}
```

The problem is that when I try to execute the previous method, I get an error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'currentExecutableTypeId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DeleteExecutableTypePost(Int64, Int64)' in 'MyWebApplication.Controllers.EditingMaliciousController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>
> Parameter name: parameters
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'currentExecutableTypeId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DeleteExecutableTypePost(Int64, Int64)' in 'MyWebApplication.Controllers.EditingMaliciousController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>
> Parameter name: parameters

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Tnx

Comment: Malicious? What are you doing? Don't do it.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you. Use blockquotes (`>`) for exception messages.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you don't have an input,textarea or select that has the name currentExceutableTypeId, it can't be bound up from the post collection.

change this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="executableTypeId" value ="@Model.MaliciousCodeExecutableType[0].Id" />
```

to this

```
<input type="hidden" name="currentExecutableTypeId" value ="@Model.MaliciousCodeExecutableType[0].Id" />
```

and all should be good

Comment: Better way is to use @Html.HiddenFor() function to bind hidden variables dont have to bother about names

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your form field is called `executableTypeId` and the action method parameter is `currentExecutableTypeId`.  Name these two the same and you should be fine.

Comment: Done but I still have the same problem

Comment: Check that the form is actually sending back a value in that field.  You could get rid of the exception by making the parameter type `long?` but that just means you'd have to handle a null value yourself.